# How to use an class Instance created by another Jenkins Plugin

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'd like to use an instance of a class that another plugin creates.

In particular, I'd like to use the instance of `MQConnection` that the [mq-notifier-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/mq-notifier-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sonymobile/jenkins/plugins/mq/mqnotifier/MQConnection.java) creates and maintains.

I've declared this plugin as a dependency in the POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sonymobile.jenkins.plugins.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>mq-notifier</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Imported the class:

```
import com.sonymobile.jenkins.plugins.mq.mqnotifier.MQConnection;
```

Tried to get the instance and add a message within the workflowstep:

```
..
public static class TestConnectionWorkflowStep extends AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution<Void> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @StepContextParameter
    private transient Run build;

    @StepContextParameter
    transient TaskListener listener;

    @Override
    protected Void run() throws Exception {
        ..
        // fill in with exchange, routing_key, data, properties
        MQConnection.getInstance().addMessageToQueue(..);
    }
}
```

It compiles fine. I've also instrumented the `MQConnection` class to log whenever a message is added.

It seems that none of my build step messages are added to the instance's queue and just silently continues.

And as expected, I do still see messages from the mq-notifier-plugin showing up fine.

I've tried using `Jenkins.getInstance().getPlugin(MQConnection.class)` but doesn't work since `MQConnection` isn't a subclass of `Plugin`.

How can I access the `MQConnection` instance from my plugin?

Answer (score 0):

getInstance() likely assumes an instance was already created when the application was started up, and it retrieves that instance. Since you're calling the method from a library, that startup hasn't happened, so there's no instance to return.

Look at the getInstance() code if you can, and also check any mq-notifier application startup or main methods in the library class. See how it instantiates the MQConnection instance, and you'll need to do the same thing.

There's probably some dependency injection going on in the other project.

> I'd like to use the instance of MQConnection that the mq-notifier-plugin creates and maintains.

You're either going to have to have the two applications running side-by-side and communicating with each other, or you're going to have to figure out how to instantiate MQConnection yourself.

> It seems that none of my build step messages are added to the instance's queue and just silently continues.

Is this running remotely then? If you have a remote MQConnection instance running then simply calling getInstance will not be enough for the two seperate programs to communicate with each other.